# How to use CSS transform: scale(); to fit child div to parent div responsively in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, scale

I am really stuck. My div contains fixed size divs, texts and images with a lot of pixel based positioning. How can I just wrap them in another div and make them scale to fit the wrapper?

This might be very similar: https://css-tricks.com/scaled-proportional-blocks-with-css-and-javascript/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using @Gershom's snippet, but keeping aspect ratio

```js
let scaledWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('scaled-wrapper')[0];

let applyScaling = scaledWrapper => {
  
  // Get the scaled content, and reset its scaling for an instant
  let scaledContent = scaledWrapper.getElementsByClassName('scaled-content')[0];
  scaledContent.style.transform = 'scale(1, 1)';
  
  let { width: cw, height: ch } = scaledContent.getBoundingClientRect();
  let { width: ww, height: wh } = scaledWrapper.getBoundingClientRect();
  
//  let scaleAmtX = ww / cw;
//  let scaleAmtY = wh / ch;
  let scaleAmtX = Math.min(ww / cw, wh / ch);
  let scaleAmtY = scaleAmtX;
  
  
  scaledContent.style.transform = `scale(${scaleAmtX}, ${scaleAmtY})`;
        
};

applyScaling(scaledWrapper);

// ---- The rest of the code is just for the demonstration ui ----
let change = () => {
  let w = parseInt(wInp.value);
  let h = parseInt(hInp.value);
  if (!isNaN(w)) scaledWrapper.style.width = `${w}px`;
  if (!isNaN(h)) scaledWrapper.style.height = `${h}px`;
  scaledWrapper.getElementsByClassName('scaled-content')[0].innerHTML = textInp.value;
  applyScaling(scaledWrapper);
};

let wInp = document.createElement('input');
wInp.setAttribute('placeholder', 'input parent width in px');
wInp.addEventListener('input', change);
wInp.value = '100';
document.body.appendChild(wInp);

let hInp = document.createElement('input');
hInp.setAttribute('placeholder', 'input parent height in px');
hInp.addEventListener('input', change);
hInp.value = '100';
document.body.appendChild(hInp);

let textInp = document.createElement('input');
textInp.setAttribute('placeholder', 'input text content');
textInp.addEventListener('input', change);
textInp.value = 'abc';
document.body.appendChild(textInp);
```

```css
.wrapper-wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 2px blue;
  position: relative;
}
.scaled-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 1;
}
.scaled-content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  background-color: #ffd0d0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-wrapper">
  <div class="scaled-wrapper">
    <div class="scaled-content">abc</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: scaled maintaining aspect ratio]

Comment: This seems to work, I should convert it to react code tho. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Let's say that some elements have a class of `.scaled-wrapper`, and such elements have a single child named `.scaled-content`. Then we have a function `applyScaling` which takes a single `.scaled-wrapper` element, and scales its child accordingly:

```js
let scaledWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('scaled-wrapper')[0];

let applyScaling = scaledWrapper => {
  
  // Get the scaled content, and reset its scaling for an instant
  let scaledContent = scaledWrapper.getElementsByClassName('scaled-content')[0];
  scaledContent.style.transform = 'scale(1, 1)';
  
  let { width: cw, height: ch } = scaledContent.getBoundingClientRect();
  let { width: ww, height: wh } = scaledWrapper.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  let scaleAmtX = ww / cw;
  let scaleAmtY = wh / ch;
  
  scaledContent.style.transform = `scale(${scaleAmtX}, ${scaleAmtY})`;
        
};

applyScaling(scaledWrapper);

// ---- The rest of the code is just for the demonstration ui ----
let change = () => {
  let w = parseInt(wInp.value);
  let h = parseInt(hInp.value);
  if (!isNaN(w)) scaledWrapper.style.width = `${w}px`;
  if (!isNaN(h)) scaledWrapper.style.height = `${h}px`;
  scaledWrapper.getElementsByClassName('scaled-content')[0].innerHTML = textInp.value;
  applyScaling(scaledWrapper);
};

let wInp = document.createElement('input');
wInp.setAttribute('placeholder', 'input parent width in px');
wInp.addEventListener('input', change);
wInp.value = '200';
document.body.appendChild(wInp);

let hInp = document.createElement('input');
hInp.setAttribute('placeholder', 'input parent height in px');
hInp.addEventListener('input', change);
hInp.value = '200';
document.body.appendChild(hInp);

let textInp = document.createElement('input');
textInp.setAttribute('placeholder', 'input text content');
textInp.addEventListener('input', change);
textInp.value = 'abc';
document.body.appendChild(textInp);
```

```css
.scaled-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px; top: 30px;
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 1;
}
.scaled-content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  background-color: #ffd0d0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="scaled-wrapper"><div class="scaled-content">abc</div></div>
```

The main idea is to take the ratio of the size between parent/child, and use that to scale the child accordingly. Note that it's important that the child's `transform-origin` is the top-left corner (having `transform-origin: 50% 50%` causes the child to be centered around the parent's top-left corner).

Also note that `applyScaling` needs to be called if the size of the parent ever changes (for example, if the parent is a percentage size of the window, and the window resizes).

Answer (score 2):

For React you can do it like this:

```
const applyScaling = (scaledWrapper, scaledContent) => {
  scaledContent.style.transform = 'scale(1, 1)';

  let { width: cw, height: ch } = scaledContent.getBoundingClientRect();
  let { width: ww, height: wh } = scaledWrapper.getBoundingClientRect();
  let scaleAmtX = Math.min(ww / cw, wh / ch);
  let scaleAmtY = scaleAmtX;
  scaledContent.style.transform = `scale(${scaleAmtX}, ${scaleAmtY})`;
};

const App = ()=>{
       const scaledWrapper=useRef();
       const scaledContent=useRef();
       useEffect(()=>{
             if (scaledWrapper.current && scaledContent.current) {
              applyScaling(scaledWrapper.current, scaledContent.current);
             }
       },[scaledWrapper.current,scaledContent.current]);

        return(
           <div ref={scaledWrapper}>
              <div ref={scaledContent}></div>
           </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: It's better to use it with window resize event listener as effect or a hook like `useWindowResize()`... since this will only apply once it rendered and won't change by window size changes.

Answer (score 1):

scale() is relative to the size of the current container.
height and width are relative to the size of the parent container.
In this case, I would simply set both height and width to 100% to fill the parent DOM element.  If you must use scale - try 100%. After setting height and width.

Comment: Nice! I did an animation that the object fills the parent on hover and set the `width: 100%` and the initial `scaleX: .25`, then on hover `scaleX: 1`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easier just by css.

```
.parent {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px
}

.children {
  scale: 0.25;
  width: 400%;
  height: 400%;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```